# Extreme Visual Glitch(?)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I don't know how to explain this in words, so I will just put screenshots.

Tried to look for somewhere where this has been reported and solved, but honestly idk the right search terms.

Some info:
I first had Windows 10 as my laptop default OS (that it came with), but I had only 4gb of ram so I installed Linux (Pop_OS!). I eventually upgraded my ram 2 days ago, and decided to download Windows 10 back, that was yesterday. I installed GeForce app and updated my GPU, installed Minecraft. I didn't play enough to see the glitch I presume, but then I remembered that I might not have Java installed, so I quit the game and installed Java SE 14. This can be the reason, but I'm not really sure. After downloading some resource packs, I decided to play it a bit more, that's when I realised the glitch, and since then it seemed to be getting worse each launch, but where it appears is random each session.

Specs:
GPU: GeForce 940MX
CPU: Intel i5-6200U
Display: 1366x768 60Hz
RAM: 4gb, 8gb (12 total)

P.S. This never happened for the first 2 (or more) years after I first bought it (new), and I am fairly positive my windows installation is not corrupt and the resource packs are not the cause of this

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]
[image: Screenshot 4]

Answer (score 1):

I think I have fixed it, at least for now. it seems to be a render/chunk loading related issue, from the pattern it was giving occasionally.

It seems optifine was causing the problem at first, so I played on vanilla and it worked. I then remembered something about VBOs improving performance and being related to object rendering or something, so I turned it on while on optifine and that completely fixed it. Not sure why this is, but I will assume this has to do with my hardware, software wouldn't make sense.

Also, resource packs weren't the problem, and I did not download Java 8, and stayed with Java 14 because I know Minecraft downloads its own Java runtime, which is java 8.

Does anyone know why VBOs matter for my laptop? this wasn't the case with the PC.